# ElasticSearch backup to S3 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, kibana

I'm trying to backup my cluster of ElasticSearch on AWS to an S3 bucket.

I've followed the following 'tutorial' : [Use Amazon S3 to Store a Single Amazon Elasticsearch Service Index](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-amazon-s3-to-store-a-single-amazon-elasticsearch-service-index/)

These are the steps I have taken:

**Create a S3 bucket (called cb-search-es-backup).**

**Create a new policy (called P_ES_SNAPSHOT_TO_S3):**

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cb-search-es-backup"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cb-search-es-backup/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

**Create a Service Role, attached the previous created policy to it**
arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/Role_ES_TO_S3

**Trust policy of the role:**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "es.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

In Kibana I've tried to use the following in the Dev Tools:

```
PUT /_snapshot/ES_BACKUP
{
"type": "s3",
    "settings": {
        "bucket": "cb-search-es-backup",
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::423628447134:role/Role_ES_TO_S3"
    }
}
```

but I receive the following response from kibana:

> {   "Message": "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform:
>   iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/Role_ES_TO_S3"
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got same error with kibana. Try to backup with [aws-es-proxy](https://github.com/abutaha/aws-es-proxy/).

If you are going to use docker image, please pass the AWS access credentials as below:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 9200:9200 -e "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -e "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" abutaha/aws-es-proxy ./aws-es-proxy -verbose -listen 0.0.0.0:9200 -endpoint https://enpoint-url
```