# Postman AWS S3 snapshot request Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, postman

Hello I need some help with sending a PUT request to my ElasticSearch on [AWS to create a snapshot in a S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-registerdirectory), with POSTMAN.

I have created a S3 bucket called cb-search-es-backup.
I've created a role, and a policy for S3 [(see:this post of mine for the steps I've taken)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706985/elasticsearch-backup-to-s3-aws).

**REQUEST URL** https://myelasticsearchendpoint.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/

**REQUEST METHOD**: PUT

**BODY** : RAW  / json

```json
{
 "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
        "bucket": "cb-search-es-backup",  // my bucketname
        "region": "eu-west-1", // region
        "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345676890:role/Role_ES_TO_S3" // my role arn
   }
 }
```

[image]

I've also tried the authorization type: 'AWS Signature', with access and secret key filled in.

Comment: Added an answer, looks like the problem in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706985/elasticsearch-backup-to-s3-aws) is the same - not passing the credentials.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are not passing AWS credentials with this request.

There is a detailed guide how to make a Postman request with AWS authentication here: [Use Postman to Call an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html).

Your Postman window might look like this:

[image: AWS Postman auth]

To do the same from python please check out `Sample python client` section of [this documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-registerdirectory), note that `AWS4Auth` object is created and it's passed as `auth` parameter to `requests.put()`:

```py
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

# Register repository

path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo' # the Elasticsearch API endpoint
url = host + path

payload = {
  ...
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)
```